# Fastest way in Python to determine if a 4x4 matrix has complex eigenvalues

Tags: python, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I am working with a 4x4 matrix which, in general, has complex valued-elements. I am trying to determine if there exists a non-real eigenvalue for this matrix; I do not necessarily care what the eigenvalue is. My current algorithm for the numpy array A (which is pre-defined by me) is as follows:

```
import scipy.linalg as SciLA 
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp

w1 = SciLA.eigvals(A) 
w2 = [mp.chop(i,tol=1e-14) for i in w1]

imag_list = [(np.imag(w2[i])) for i in range(0,len(w1))] 
imag_num  = np.sign(len([x for x in imag_list if x != 0]))
```

Using %timeit, the code takes around 1.43 ms per loop (after testing over 1000 loops) for a simple 4x4 matrix. However, I feel that there should be a simpler way of just checking if a certain matrix has complex eigenvalues. I also need the code to go faster, as I am looping over many 4x4 matrices. Any suggestions for possible packages or mathematical/numerical techniques to aid in simplifying the code and/or speeding it up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't [guranteed](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/1553/complex-eigenvalues.html) for a n x n matrix to have exactly n complex eigenvalues, counted with multiplicity?

Comment: I assume Joshuah is looking to check if the values are "strictly complex", i.e. have a non-null imaginary part. Indeed, this is what their code does.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean non-real. I will edit the question to make this apparent.

Comment: Could you add a sample matrix of the kind you need? I went with `A = np.random.normal(size=(4,4)) + 1j * np.random.normal(size=(4,4))` for a quick test., but my `%%timeit` (skipping the imports) results in 153 µs ± 4.61 µs for that matrix, which is curious - ten times faster faster than your reported time.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment above, I am going to assume that you are looking to see if any if the values is non-real, i.e. has a non-null imaginary part. This isn't strictly a solution, but I'm guessing it'll be close enough for what you want:

The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues. If this trace is non-real, certainly at least one of these eigenvalues must be non-real. So just check if this is the case, and if so you can be sure that there is a non-real eigenvalue.

This condition isn't perfect, of course, one can easily find matrices with a real trace but some non-real eigenvalues. Therefore, if the trace *is* real, you should fall back to the method above to figure out whether the eigenvalues are all real or not. However, for most applications, most matrices will have a non-real trace, and so your execution time should be much shorter since all you need to compute is the trace.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty unfortunate. It would certainly be more costly, but you could try essentially the same trick with the determinant instead of the trace. 

In fact, I *think* that, for any fixed k, the sum of the determinants of centered k-minors  (this is the trace for k=1 and determinant for k=4) might admit the same trick, of being non-real only if some eigenvalues are non-real (if I recall correctly, it has to be equal to the sum of the products of all k distinct eigenvalues).

Answer (score 0):

I guess what is make your code bad is that you are building three lists from the response and using loops for that. Use numpy vectorized operations instead

```py
# This will tell you if all the eigenvalues are (nearly) real
np.allclose(SciLA.eigvals(A).imag, 0)
```